# SQL Server transactional replication

Tags: sql-server

I have a transaction publication setup on SQL Server 2014 that replicates to SQL Server 2008, then I use merge replication to synchronize to a SQL Server CE database on a Win CE device. The problem is that changes came from the transaction publication isn't replicating through merge publication into the SQL Server CE database on the Win CE device while if I change anything in the SQL Server 2008 database, it's replicating just fine.

I already tried snapshot publication and changing "Action when name is in use" property on the publication.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will encounter a similar issue here's what worked for me:

- Run the following on your merge publication database :

```
    EXEC sp_changemergearticle 

    @publication = 'MyPublication', 

    @article = 'MyArticle', 

    @property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 

    @value = 'true';
```

For more info about the problem read this article :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017